# Exception when working with JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When I try to export a report to Excel *XLS* file exception is raised, in the Internet I found that it's because *POI* version is must be 3.6 or later, I've deleted previous versions, and leave only *POI 3.6*, but it didn't help:

```
[#|2012-06-20T04:06:02.593+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=160;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[JasperToExcel]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet JasperToExcel threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getCreationHelper()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper;
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.openWorkbook(JRXlsExporter.java:204)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:366)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:187)
    at servlet.JasperToExcel.processRequest(JasperToExcel.java:119)
    at servlet.JasperToExcel.doGet(JasperToExcel.java:155)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

I'm using *Jasper Reports 3.7.4*.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What JR version are you using?

Comment: As [you can see](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/3.7.4/jasperreports-3.7.4.pom) the JR 3.7.4 is using the POI 3.5-FINAL version.

Comment: I've added POI 3.5-FINAL but it is not working, also delete another versions of POI

Comment: I've deleted all other versions from Glassfish "applications/myapp" dir, and now it's working, Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasper Reports 4.0 works properly with POI 3.6., but your version is 3.7.4. You need POI 3.5-FINAL. Find [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/3.7.4)

Regards